# No Aptana Samples?

Tags: aptana

I just discovered Aptana, and I think it really has some potential. One bad thing i've noticed is that my "samples" pane is completely empty? I just downloaded "Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.9.201202141038"

How can I get all the samples to appear? If it matters, I'm interested in having Javascript and jquery samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no built-in samples at the moment (I assume some will be added in the future).

You can create your own samples via the `rubles` scripting infrastructure, now that this ticket was resolved - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3772

Instructions on how to do so are at: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Creating+a+new+sample#Creatinganewsample-Creatinganewsample

Comment: BTW, if you have a good samples that you would like to see shipped with the Studio, you can open a ticket at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs with your zipped sample, and we will do our best to place it in.